# Less attribute "selector starts" with different suffixes

Tags: css, css-selectors, attributes, less

I have an attribute selector that targets two HTML elements:

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lavender;
}

div[class^="tag-"] {
  outline: 2px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-start"></div>
<div class="tag-end"></div>
```

Can I create a Less selector that targets both using the attribute selector as a starting point?

Comment: Hey MauF I have done my best to help you improve your CSS selector. I have no idea how this question relates to Less however, so if my answer is not what you're looking for can you please edit your question to clarify that

Answer (score 0):

Your current selector may not be the best solution as per the [CSS Level 4 Specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview).

In the below snippet your selector will match only examples one and two because [the attribute-substrings selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#attribute-substrings) you're using will only match the beginning of an attribute value, not each space separated value in a classlist:

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lavender;
}

div[class^="tag-"] {
  outline: 2px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-start">1</div>
<div class="tag-end">2</div>
<div class="will-not-work tag-test">3</div>
```

Since all less code transpiles to CSS, less won't be able to match anything CSS itself can't, short of including all possible permutations that could follow `tag-`...

I suggest you use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) here rather than a class.

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lavender;
}

div[data-tag] {
  outline: 2px solid tomato;
}

div[data-tag="start"] {
  outline: 4px solid hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div data-tag="start">1</div>
<div data-tag="end">2</div>
<div data-tag="test" class="will-work">3</div>
```